# Return an int value to Database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcombobox

I am working on an application which makes it easier for employees to return lost luggage.

I'm working on a screen which registers a piece of luggage.
The status ComboBox is filled with data from the database, as well as the CustomerID combobox.
SCREEN:
http://gyazo.com/d81c7c2377c79eb2b42d6f101fb8d5f5

Now the ComboBox fetches an SQL query, and shows a firstname. But the customer has a customerID as well.  For now i have a method which sets the value of the variable customerId, with:

```
lug.setCustomerID(String.valueOf(CustomerID.getSelectedItem()));
```

But then it sets its value to 'Khoa'.

How can i show a name in my combobox, but get the INT value of the customerID?

Comment: Map between id and name?

Comment: @almas shaikh what if there are 2 customers with the same name?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt((String)CustomerID.getSelectedItem())`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just adding strings to the ComboBox you can add an object with both ID and String.
You need to override the toString() function of your class from which you create the customer object.

```
public class Customer {
  private String name;
  private int id;

  public Customer(String label, int identifier) {
     name = label;
     id = identifier;
  }

  public getId() { return id; }

  @Overrider public String toString() { return name; }
}
```

You can when using an object out of that class

```
lug.setCustomerID(CustomerID.getSelectedItem().getId());
```

Comment: The idea is ok (I'm tempted to up-vote it) but making public access to `Customer` fields breaks the encapsulation principle. Note: class' names start with capital letter as per Java Code Conventions.

Comment: I don't think it was necessary to get the idea, but updated the class definition

Comment: Not necessary to get the idea but necessary for both correctness and completeness. 1+ for your edit :)

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your data in simple bean (e.g. Customer)  with 2 fields: int id; String firstName and toString must return firstName.
After declare your combobox as `JComboBox<Customer>`.
The result will look like `lug.setCustomerID(CustomerID.getSelectedItem().getId());`